# Moving some functions from mainactivity into another class

Tags: android, class

I have a addAllToGroup click function and I use the DialogWithRadioButtonM in many different places, is it possible to place DialogWithRadioButtonM() and redioGroup1() functions in a separate file(class)? Here is my code:
i tried to put it in a class but i get error for onclicklistener in it and also i dont know how to use context in a nonActivity java file. sorry, I am new in android and java thanks for help.

```
public void addAllToGroup(View view) {
        csM = new String[6];
        //dialogTitle="Add This to Group";
        csM[0] = "Add to Group 1";
        csM[1] = "Add to Group 2";
        csM[2] = "Add to Group 3";
        csM[3] = "Add to Group 4";
        csM[4] = "Add to Group 5";
        csM[5] = "Remove Grouping";
        DialogWithRadioButtonM("Add Selected to Group");
    }

    public void DialogWithRadioButtonM(String str){

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle(str);
        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(csM, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                Log.i("TAG2", "onCreate: "+item);

                switch(item)
                {
                    case 0: backFromDialogM=0; break;
                    case 1: backFromDialogM=1; break;
                    case 2: backFromDialogM=2; break;
                    case 3: backFromDialogM=3; break;
                    case 4: backFromDialogM=4; break;
                    case 5: backFromDialogM=5; break;
                    case 6: backFromDialogM=6; break;
                    case 7: backFromDialogM=7; break;
                }

                redioGroup1(backFromDialogM);
                alertDialogM.dismiss();
            }
        });
        alertDialogM = builder.create();
        alertDialogM.show();

    }


    public void redioGroup1(int group) {

        int iCount = myRecycler.getAdapter().getItemCount();
        MyDateBase mydbM = new MyDateBase(MainActivity.this);
        final SQLiteDatabase databaseM = mydbM.getWritableDatabase();
        String strCL = "cl" + "0";
        String rawQueryM="";
        for (int i = 0; i < iCount; i++) {
            if (mAdapter.itemList.get(i).isChecked()) {
                mAdapter.itemList.get(i).getuSentId();
                rawQueryM ="UPDATE wp_words SET " + strCL + " =" + group + " WHERE wid= " + mAdapter.itemList.get(i).getuSentId();
                databaseM.execSQL(rawQueryM);
                Log.i("tog", "" + mAdapter.itemList.get(i).getuSentId());
            }
        }
        Log.i("togf", "" + rawQueryM);

    }
```

thanks

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: There is no error. it works properly. i only want to place this function in a separate class (another java file) .

Comment: "i tried to put it in a class but i get error for onclicklistener" what was the error?

Answer (score 0):

Your "DialogWithRadioButtonM" Class depends of the outer class in which it is.
You have to make "DialogWithRadioButtonM" not dependant of other variables/objects outside it, or you cannot move it in a stand alone Class file.
For example: "backFromDialogM" and "alertDialogM" are not declared INSIDE DialogWithRadioButtonM but somewhere else in the same file.